# Facebook Progressive Jpegs

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, libgdx

I am trying to download facebook images and use them as Textures. However, facebook provides progressive JPEG files, which aren't supported in LIBGDX. Does anybody know how to get baseline JPEGs from facebook? There seem to be several URL's that work with the Graph API.

EDIT

Let me clarify my question. I'm not trying to save any single images, I am using Facebook API to grab user's profile picture, and friend list. Converting pictures for each user does not make sense.

Comment: "I am trying" How? Show us your code.

Comment: The code is not the question at hand. It is common knowledge that LibGDX does not support progressive jpegs. My question is how can I get baseline JPEGS from facebook.

Comment: You can’t. FB does not store images in progressive _and_ baseline just for you.

Answer (score 0):

The use of a Picture modifier like " Format Factory " I find works well with the conversion of Jpg,Png,Bmp (ect) to other formats. Its free to download and use, and is great for music, and video also..

Comment: I'm not trying to convert any images.

Comment: As your problem stands, you will have to convert your pictures, and save them as baseline jpeg

Comment: Let me clarify my question. I'm not trying to save any single images, I am using Facebook API to grab user's profile picture, and friend list. Converting pictures for each user does not make sense.

Comment: If the component that you want to _use_ those images in does not support progressive JPEGs, then you will _have to_ convert them – or give up on using them with that component. Which of those two options makes more “sense”, is for you to decide.